# How to unbind/off specific event handler from an element in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Angular's built-in jqLite doesn't support namespace for unbind/off. So If I use unbind/off its completely wipes out all the events attached to an element.

How do I unbind/off the specific event handler from an event in angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`var listnerFn = function (){} // listener function.
angular.element(el).on('click', listenerFn) // event registration.
angular.element(el).off('click', listenerFn) // event de registration`.

where el is the element reference on which events need to be registered.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is correct and is the way to unbind a specific event handler from a specific event. While it's true that jqLite doesn't support namespaces, this doesn't use namespaces. A namespace would be `click.myNamespace` or just `.myNamespace`.